# Display username login logout ASP

Tags: asp.net

I am building a small web app and I need to create a login page. I have my own MS-SQL server database with a table Users in it, and the login would retrieve information from the table to validate the user. 
Now, when the user logs in, I want to be able to see the username and a logout link next to it. But, I am not sure how to achieve it. I read about Login Name control, but it seems it only works with membership provider. 
Is there any way I can do this?thanks~~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a Login control as shown:

```
<asp:Login ID="LoginCtrl" runat="server" DestinationPageUrl="Defaul.aspx"></asp:Login>
```

In Code Behind

```
Private Sub Log_Authenticate(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.AuthenticateEventArgs) Handles LoginCtrl.Authenticate
    If LoginCtrl.UserName = "Username" AndAlso LoginCtrl.Password = "Password" Then
        e.Authenticated = True
End If

void MyLogin_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
{
    if(UserName == "Username" && Password == "Password")
    e.Authenticated = true;
}
```

Comment: thanks for pointing me in the right direction. But I created a layout template for the login control and also a login button. How can i handle the login click event, using the authenticate function?

Answer (score 0):

From what you have written i assume upon successfull login you must be setting some session variable to hold your login detail, and you are not using any buitin capability of utilities provided by .net like membership provider. in this case when the login details are successfull set a session variable which holds the user unique identification number.

Example:

when login is successful you can set a session variable ["uid"] to the userid. In your page load event check for this variable to see if the user is authenticated or not.
if the user has been authenticated then do you stuff else if the userid session variable is null or 0 redirect to login page.

Now for showing login/logout nad name you can create a user control with a table of 2 rows.
in each row add a panel panel1 in top row and panel 2 on botton row. set their visiblity to hidden

Now in top row panel panel1 drag a link button with text as login. On click event redirect user to login page.
in panel 2 drag a label say label1 and a link button with text logout.
on logout click event  destroy the session and redirect to login page.

now in the usercontrol load event check uid session variable if uid is valid the set the label1 text to username . make panel2 visible and do the reverse in case of invalid uid variable.
Use this control everywhere you nedd to show login/logout details.
hope this is enough to get started.....